# Install Alcatraz on XCode beta 6.3

Tags: xcode, package, beta, alcatraz

How can I install Alcatraz over XCode 6.3 beta?

If I run `curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/supermarin/Alcatraz/master/Scripts/install.sh | sh`
 it works just for my non beta XCode.

Answer (score 6):

@saiday has combined the below steps into a single terminal command:

```
find ~/Library/Application\ Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins -name Info.plist -maxdepth 3 | xargs -I{} defaults write {} DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs -array-add `defaults read /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Info DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUID`
```

The above script performs steps 2 and 3 for you.

1. Make sure Alcatraz is installed and working in release XCode
2. Determine the UUID of your beta version by running the following in your Terminal:

   ```
   defaults read /Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Info DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUID
   ```
3. Run the following in your Terminal:

   ```
   defaults write ~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/Alcatraz.xcplugin/Contents/Info.plist -array-add DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs [REPLACE WITHUUID FROM STEP TWO]
   ```

This adds the UUID for the current beta to the list of acceptable platforms for Alcatraz. Your UUID should look something like this: 992275C1-432A-4CF7-B659-D84ED6D42D3F

Comment: This kind of works (plugins work inside Xcode) but Package manager is missing in Window menu.

Comment: The UUID in my current comment is now outdated. I've updated my answer with more thorough steps.

Comment: combine these two commands will be one snippet 
```find ~/Library/Application\ Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins -name Info.plist -maxdepth 3 | xargs -I{} defaults write {} DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs -array-add `defaults read /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Info DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUID`
```

Answer (score 3):

I made a script that makes this automatic for any version of Xcode.
Switch to the new version of Xcode, by indicating the path to its Developer folder.

```
- sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode-NEW.app/Contents/Developer
```

Download the script from [GitHub](https://github.com/TwiterZX/Xcode-plugins-update), run it, then restart Xcode.

Comment: It says `unnable to find the Xcode.app location, Exiting...`. I need to put the file inside any path?